# Put a password to my QGIS project

Tags: qgis

I currently have a project which I would like to put a password on when opening it, I am not using a database but simple configurations in the layers. How can I protect my QGZ project?

Comment: 7-Zip (freeware) allows you to put a password on a zip file.  Place your QGIS project file and associated data into a single directory, zip it with a password.